# How to insert dictionary function into another dictionary function while changing key to id_number?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key

The objective of the problem is to:

- instantiate an empty dictionary called `pokedex`
- define a new function that will take arguments for `pokedex, poke_id, poke_name, poke_type`
- use my dictionary function `create_pokemon` and add a new `key:value` pair to the `pokedex` dictionary where the `key` is `poke_id` and the `value` is the newly-created pokemon dictionary

I created a dictionary function: `create_pokemon(poke_id, poke_name, poke_type)`. The keys are `'hp','defense', 'special_defense'`, and the list goes on.

This is my `create_pokemon` function:

````
    new_pokemon= {

        'poke_id': poke_id,
        'poke_name': poke_name,
        'poke_type': poke_type,
        'hp': np.random.randint(400,501),
        'attack': np.random.randint(50,101),
        'defense': np.random.randint(50,101),
        'special_attack' : np.random.randint(100,151),
        'special_defense': np.random.randint(100,151),
        'speed': np.random.randint(0,101)      

    }```





so when I display pokedex, it should look something like:

```{1: {'attack': 64,
  'defense': 59,
  'hp': 495,
  'poke_id': 1,
  'poke_name': 'charmander',
  'poke_type': 'fire',
  'special_attack': 100,```
````

Comment: Are you just trying to figure out the syntax to add a dictionary to another dictionary?

Comment: `This is my create_pokemon function`: I can't see any functions...

Answer (score 1):

```
newPokemon = create_pokemon()
id = newPokemon['poke_id']
pokedex[id] = newPokemon
```

should do the trick, unless I'm missing something in the problem description

Comment: Since the inputs to `create_pokemon` include the poke_id, the variables `newPokemon` and `id` aren't needed: `pokedex[poke_id] = create_pokemon(poke_id, poke_name, poke_type)`

Comment: Yes, that's correct, as long as we're going with the functions provided. I didn't see any stubs and it seemed like the confusion was around creating a dictionary with dictionary values, so I tried to clear that portion up a bit.